# lock a transaction (series of selects and updates) in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a table and several threads (systems) which read a specific column from the table and update it. So my query is as follow:

```
Begin;
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE <condition1>
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1 WHERE <condition1>
Commit;
```

I want to make sure at any time only one thread can select and update that column. What is the best solution ?

PS: To the best of my knowledge, using transactions in SQL Server locks all the resources in the transaction but I have no idea about PostgreSQL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kordirko has correctly pointed out that `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is the basic feature used for this.

Note that it will not take a predicate lock. So if you `SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE id = 42 FOR UPDATE` and there is no row with `id = 42`, *no lock is taken*. There's no "reservation" created on  ID 42. Somebody else can jump in and create it between your `SELECT` and a subsequent `INSERT`.

If you're trying to deal with that, you may wish to look into `SERIALIZABLE` isolation mode. I think MS SQL Server, which you're used to, defaults to `SERIALIZABLE` isolation.

You can instead write:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE <condition1>
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1 WHERE <condition1>
COMMIT;
```

I strongly suggest setting up some concurrency tests to demonstrate that this works as you expect, of course.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for your explanation. I think you are right, MS SQL transactions are serializable by default. Also I read PostgreSQL manual and found out there is a high level lock for a table that prevent any reading and writing "LOCK TABLE chunk_prop IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE". Do you have any idea about the performance of this solution versus your solution ? Thank you again

Comment: @MajidDarabi An `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock is fast and cheap, so long as you don't mind totally blocking all other access to the table. You eliminate all concurrency at a *table* level, not just row level. So if you have few updates, you can use it well, but if you have lots of updates it'll cause you much pain. `EXCLUSIVE MODE` blocks only writers, not readers, and is slightly less painful, but still gives you no write concurrency. Really depends on your workload, so as usual it's a matter of test-and-see.

Answer (score 2):

The finest level lock in SQL is a row lock.

A column cannot be locked, the database always places a lock at the whole row (all columns of the row).

You can use [a `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE):

```
Begin;
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE <condition1> FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1 WHERE <condition1> ;
Commit;
```

`SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` works like ordinary select (it retrieves rows from the table), but in addtion it places locks on all retrieved rows, preventing them from being modified by other transactions until the current transaction ends.

You can also use [`RETURNING` clause in `UPDATE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html):

```
Begin;
UPDATE tbl SET col = col + 1 WHERE <condition1> 
   RETURNING col - 1 AS col;
Commit;
```

The `UPDATE` statement always places a write lock on the modified record.

The `RETURNING` clause causes to return values, like ordinary `SELECT`, however it returns row values after modification (post-update row values), therefore a `col - 1` expression is used in the above example, to compute the column value before it was incremented.

Please take a look at this demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d0f4/3

The advantage of the second way (UPDATE+RETURNING clause) is that the record is accessed only once, in contrast to the first method, when the row must be selected first by the `SELECT` statement (first access), then it is updated using the `UPDATE` statement (second access).

Comment: Thanks kordirko! your solution is excellent but it doesn't prevent reading from that row. I went through several solutions and finally after reading PostgreSQL manual I found out using "LOCK TABLE tbl IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE" may help you to lock a table for reading and writing. ( I couldn't found any thing for a row)